# Prove that $\det(A)\neq 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix, $n$ even, with even diagonal elements and all other elements odd integers. Prove that  $\det(A)\neq 0$.  Can anyone give me a hint? Thank you.

Comment: Use [Laplace's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace.27s_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix) to prove with induction, that $\det A$ is odd.

Answer (score 14):

**Hint:** Compute the determinant of $A$ reduced modulo $2$.

Answer (score 1):

The determinant is an odd integer then.